# Basis of the Kernel and Range

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M_{3×3}$ be the vector space of 3 × 3 matrices. 
Define $T$ : $M_{3×3}$ → $M_{3×3}$ by $T (A) = A + A^T$ .

(a) Show T is a linear transformation

(b) Find a basis for the kernel of $T$. What is the dimension of the kernel?

(c) Find a basis for the range of $T$ . What is the dimension of the range?

With respect to (b) and (c): How does one find the basis of the kernel and the range? And the dimension for the kernel and the range would be the number of free variables and the number of pivots respectively, correct?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need any matrix reduction. Just characterize the kernel and the image. Finding bases is then easy.

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume that $M_{3\times3}$ consists of real matrices.

(a) For every $A,B \in M_{3\times3},\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
T(\alpha A+ B)&=&\alpha A+B+(\alpha A+B)^T=\alpha A+B+\alpha A^T+B^T\\
&=&\alpha A+\alpha A^T+B+B^T=\alpha(A+A^T)+B+B^T\\
&=&\alpha T(A)+T(B).
\end{eqnarray}

(b) Given $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{3\times3}$ we have
$$
T(A)=0 \iff A^T=-A \iff a_{ji}=-a_{ij} \quad \forall i,j.
$$
In particular we have $a_{ii}=0$ for every $i$.

It follows that
$$
\ker T=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0\end{array}\right):\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\},
$$
hence $\ker T=\text{span}\{K_1,K_2,K_3\}$, where
$$
K_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right),\
K_2=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{array}\right),\
K_3=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{array}\right).
$$
The latter also shows that $\dim \ker T=3$, since 
$$
aK_1+bK_2+cK_3=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0\end{array}\right)=0 \iff a=b=c=0.
$$

(c) Given $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{3\times3}$ we set $A'=T(A)=(a'_{ij})$. Then
$a'_{ij}=a_{ij}+a_{ji}$ for every $i,j$. It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
A'&=&\left(\begin{array}{ccc}2a_{11}&a_{12}+a_{21}&a_{13}+a_{31}\\a_{21}+a_{12}&2a_{22}&a_{23}+a_{32}\\a_{31}+a_{13}&a_{32}+a_{23}&2a_{33}\end{array}\right)\\
&=&2a_{11}E_{11}+2a_{22}E_{22}+2a_{33}E_{33}+(a_{12}+a_{21})E+(a_{13}+a_{31})F+(a_{23}+a_{32})G,
\end{eqnarray}
with
\begin{eqnarray}
E_{11}&=&\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right),\ 
E_{22}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right),\
E_{33}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),\\
E&=&\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right),\
F=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{array}\right),\
G=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{array}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Since
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3a_iE_{ii}+bE+cF+dG=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1&b&c\\
b&a_2&d\\
c&d&a_3
\end{array}\right)=0 \iff a_1=a_2=a_3=b=c=d=0,
$$
the matrices $E_{11},E_{22},E_{33},E,F,G$ form a basis for the range of $T$, and therefore its dimension is $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

1. $A\in\ker T$ if and only if $A+A^T=0$, that is $A$ is …
2. $T(A)=A+A^T$ is symmetric; is every symmetric matrix in the range of $T$?

It's not difficult then to find bases for the two subspaces.